# Creating a vertically scrollable div from unknown height

Tags: html, css

I have a popup div which has a height of 100%.

```
.popup{
height:100%;
}
```

I have gone ahead and created a 60% margin top

```
.popup{
margin-top:60%;
}
```

and so only `40%` of space is available at the bottom end of the popup.

In the `40%` bottom space,i want to have a scrollable div container of maybe height of `500px`. This does not work and only the `40%` space is available and no scrolling bars appear.

How can i have `500px` on the `40%` space available?.

Comment: Any fiddle with HTML also

Comment: Provide Your Trying Code

Comment: I am working with the popup class exclusively and the bottom half div. `.popup{margin-top:60%;} .bottomhalfdiv{height:500px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet:

```css
body,
html,
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper-top, .wrapper-bottom {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
.wrapper-top {
    height: 60%;
}
.wrapper-bottom {
    height: 40%;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="wrapper-top">
   <div class="inner">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-bottom">
   <div class="inner">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main{
  width:100%;
  height:350px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.top{
  width:100%;
  height:60%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.bottom{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:38%;
  border:1px solid #ff6600;
  padding:5px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom">
  <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: K Try It Once It Should Have 40% Height And Content Have 500px Height Ok

Answer (score 0):

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/wx2v7pj6/

```
.popup {  
    margin-top: 60%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 250px;
}
```

And html

```
<div class="popup">
 <div class="inner">
 abcd<br/>....
 </div>
</div>
```